# demo will not loop

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I made a little demo of a pong game. It's very simple but it won't want to loop.
What am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
move1();

function move1() {
    $('.pong.links').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+20 }, 1200, "swing");
    $('.pong.rechts').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+20 }, 1200, "swing");
    //$('.ball').animate({left: '+=150', top: '+=130'}, 600, "linear").animate({left: '+=110', top: '-=95'}, 600, "linear");
    $('.ball').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+135, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+180 }, 1200, "linear")
        .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+30, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+415 }, 1200, "linear");
    move2();
};
function move2() {
    $('.pong.links').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+80 }, 500, "swing").delay(300)
                    .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+20 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.pong.rechts').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+20 }, 500, "swing").delay(700)
                    .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+60 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.ball').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+0, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+280 }, 500, "linear")
        .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+30, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+0}, 1200, "linear");
    //$('.ball').animate({left: '-=90', top: '-=35'}, 600, "linear").animate({left: '-=170', top: '+=35'}, 1000, "linear");
    move3();
};
function move3() {
    $('.pong.links').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+40 }, 500, "swing").delay(800)
                    .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+20 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.pong.rechts').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+40 }, 500, "swing").delay(300)
                     .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+80 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.ball').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+0, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+50 }, 500, "linear")
              .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+135, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+280}, 1200, "linear")
              .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+100, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+415}, 1200, "linear");
    move4();
};
function move4() {
    $('.pong.links').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+100 }, 500, "swing").delay(300)
                    .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+0 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.pong.rechts').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+40 }, 500, "swing").delay(300)
                     .animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+80 }, 500, "swing");
    $('.ball').animate({ 'top': $('.pong_frame').position().top+0, 'left': $('.pong_frame').position().left+0 }, 1500, "linear");
    move1();
};  

});
```

---

html:

```
 < div class="pong_frame">

 < div class="pong links"></div>

 < div class="pong rechts"></div>

< div class="ball"></div>

 < /div>
```

css:

```
body, .pong_frame{padding:0;margin:0;}

.pong_frame{width:450px; height:150px; border:solid 1px #999; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}

.pong{width:8px; height:50px; background:#9cd1aa; position:absolute;}

.pong.links{left:0px; top:0px;}

.pong.rechts{right:0px; top:130px;}

.ball{width:15px; height:15px; background:#9cd1aa; border-radius:15px; margin-left:10px;  margin-right:10px; position:absolute; top:0px;}
```

---

---

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/7n5f2/1/

Comment: Possibly discount my answer! It appears it does work, might be getting the wrong end of the stick, thats cool BTW...

Comment: Just as a heads up, instead of querying for the top position and adding 20 or whatever just use `.animate({'top' : '+=20'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute a function and call another when is finish... and at the end, call again the first one...

Yeap, you are creating a loop, but with a big problem:

### **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

That's why your animation does not repeat... because are overflowing the memory.

(And if it does.. IT'S not recomended to do it with a Max call stack Warning)

---

If you want to run a loop between functions, I recomend to use the **setInterval()** and **setTimeout()** method.

Start with:

```
var timeToLoop = '8600'; // set in how many miliseconds the animation will repeat
var inter=setInterval(move1,timeToLoop); // time to wait to start looping
move1(); // Start
```

And then, in each function minus the last one... add:

```
var t=setTimeout(function(){move2()},2400); // After 2.4 seconds, I will execute the next function
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tnTmE/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention, you will have to adjust the time between functions... I just put some. Good Luck